# Is it possible to use multiple index data directory in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm new in Apache Lucene/Solr.

I try to move from Elasticsearch to Apache Solr.

So, I have a question about following index data location configuration.

**in Elasticsearch**

> # Can optionally include more than one lo
>   # the locations (a la RAID 0) on a file l
>   # space on creation. For example:
>   #
>   #path.data: /path/to/data1,/path/to/data2

**in Apache Solr**

```
<dataDir>/var/data/solr/</dataDir>
```

I want to configure multiple index data directory like Elasticsearch in Apache Solr.

Is it possible?

How I can reach the goal?

Is it possible multiple index data directory in Apache Solr?

Is it possible multiple index data directory in Apache Solr?

Comment: what made you move from elasticsearch to solr? just curious

Comment: Restarting time of elasticsearch instance is very slow (several hours!) in our environment. We don't solve this problem so, we try to find alternative solution like solr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can reach the goal?

That depends on the reason, why you need multiple index directories.
By default, solr does not support multiple of index-locations using the `<dataDir>`.

So the question is: why you need that?

For high availability (for the case, if one storage/index-path is not avalaible?)? Or for performance issue? To spread the disk I/O over many drives?

In this case, there are some other solr features/products you should use, like [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud),  [distributed search](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)

Comment: Thanks your feedback. 
I think multiple index locations are more advantages for disk I/O performance and flexible disk storage size management.

Comment: Does SolrCloud support multiple index locations? It doesn't look like so. If that's the case, how do I spread the disk I/O over many drives?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way to configure this with Solr at this time (Sept 2020).

I agree it would be advantageous from a performance perspective when a host has multiple volumes available, to spread the data like you would with Cassandra, Elasticsearch, etc.

An alternative is to run more than one instance on a host, but that has many other drawbacks.

Alternatively you would have to use OS level tools like LVM in linux to create a volume that is spread across existing drives or file systems.

Because my file systems were pre-existing, I had to use `dd` to create sparse files, and `lvm` to create a logical block device that wrapped across those files.  This was not the most efficient thing to do, but worked.